# Is there a limit to the amount of curated data that can be retrieved?

Tags: curated-data, entity

Mathematica provides access to curated data on [many entities](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EntityTypes.html). For access to some of the curated data (e.g. current exchange rates), users must have an internet connection. Is there a limit (i.e. quota) on how much data can be retrieved from the curated data?

I know that there is a limit to the number of WolframAlpha calls. I am wondering if there is any limit associated with retrieving curated data.

Comment: Not that I’ve ever hit and I’ve asked for lots of it. On the other hand if you ask for too much you’ll go crazy because the data retrieval is often super slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two types of services that require "credits" in Wolfram World.  First, there are [Service Credits](https://www.wolfram.com/service-credits/) for things like sending email, doing `WebSearch` and Text Translations.  These credits are for functions that rely on external services.  Then there are [Cloud Credits](https://www.wolfram.com/cloud-credits/) for web executed Wolfram items such as forms and APIs.  All of the documentation on curated data and hosted resources (that I have read) indicate it is completely free for users and does not need either sort of credit.  I too have done extensive downloading of Entity data and the only limit I hit was with my own processing power and memory.  I have a feeling it is monitored, but unless you have an extreme use case, it would never be an issue.